# How to customize height css based on current div size using angular2?

Tags: angular

I have the following html:

```
<div style="height:300px;width:300px;background:red;display:block;">
<div style="height:30px;width:300px;background:blue;display:block;">
</div>
<div style="overflow:auto;height:100px;">
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
Test<br>
</div>
</div>
```

My problem is, the scrollbar is currently showing at "height:100px". I want the height to be sized based on the size of the window, so that if I change the height of the outermost div to say, 200px or 400px, the height of the innermost div can be automatically adjusted. Is there a way for me to do this within the template itself? I want to do something like:

```
<div style="overflow:auto;height:{{ -insert javascript to get height of the containing div so this value can be correct without hardcoding- }}px;"></div>
```

I would have preferred to omit the height, but it is required if you want scrollbars to appear.
Is this possible? If not, what is a good alternative?

NOTE: I want the scrollbar to be on the whole height of the div in 'red' and not the entire box. (meaning I do not want to see a scrollbar that overlaps both red and blue)

Answer (score 0):

add overflow:auto to outer most div and remove overflow and height of second child of parent in your code

Comment: I do not want the whole div to be scrollable, only the box in "red". Assuming that the box was resizable (changes in height) I want the appropriate px # to be in there to ensure the scrollbar takes up the full height of the red div.

Comment: you want blue box as sticky and other child box scrollable with red box?

Comment: instead of height: 100px try height: calc( 100% - 30px );